# Problem with the compiling of the STLport under Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, stlport

I am trying to build the latest version of stlprot under Snow Leopard.

Steps for the compiling i have made:

```
./configure
sudo make && make check
```

make && make check are working fine. 
the problem occurs, if i call 'sudo make install', i get an error:

```
/bin/sh: /usr/local/include/stlport: No such file or directory
Can't create /usr/local/include/stlport
make[1]: *** [install-headers] Error 1
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

Does anyone have had similar problem with the stlport?

PS
My system specification:
Snow Leopard 10.6.4
gcc version: gcc version 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a wild guess: maybe they're doing "mkdir /usr/local/include/stlport", without the "-p" switch and /usr/local/include doesn't exist yet. That would trigger a no such file or directory error. Try running this before "sudo make install":

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include
```

or maybe even go the full way:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/include/stlport
```

Comment: The manual adding of desired folders had solved the problem. But i get an other error while the testing (form STLport/build/test/unit with make check): make: *** [check-stldbg] Segmentation fault